# Langevin dynamics with position dependent random force

Tags: conventions, noise, brownian-motion

Suppose I want to solve for some Langevin dynamics. Let us consider a single particle:
$$m\ddot {\mathbf r}=-\eta\dot{\mathbf r}+\mathbf F$$
where $\mathbf r$ is position, $\eta$ is viscosity force and $m$ is mass. Usually $\mathbf F =\mathbf F(t)$ (only depends on time) is some Gaussian random force. However, is there a similar model to solve when $\mathbf F$ is position dependent $\mathbf F(\mathbf r)$ or both position and time dependent $\mathbf F(\mathbf r,t)$? I am ok with remaining with simple models. For example, can this be solved for a position dependent force such that $\langle \mathbf F(\mathbf r)\rangle=0$ and $\langle F_i(\mathbf r)F_i(\mathbf r')\rangle=C(r_i- r_i')$? How are these models called?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: [Thermal Equilibrium with the Wiener Potential: Testing the Replica Variational Approximation](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9507099)? I guess the keyword would be disordered potentials.